# Changing Finder preferences 'Copy 6 items' etc

Tags: keyboard, finder, customization

I am trying to configure a left-handed keyboard layout on my Mac.

The only real issue I'm having at the moment is changing the shortcuts for copy / paste. I easily can change this for (almost) every app using the the `App Shortcuts` in preferences.

The problem is that Finder, when copying multiple items, will word it like 'Copy 6 items' and so in those situations my new keyboard shortcut won't work.

Is there a way I can set Finder so that it always uses just the word 'Copy' regardless of how many items there are? If I can sort that, then I imagine my shortcut will work as intended.

Comment: Which OS version? Have you actually tried changing the Copy shortcut? (What could be more left-handed that Command C?)

Comment: No-one seems to have found any way round the 'smart' menu items on Mac - there are a few questions on here about similar efforts - but I'm puzzled… what makes a keyboard left-handed?

Comment: I had a feeling that may be the case! As I've never found a forum post where someone has managed it successfully... the problem is that Im using the mouse and have to take my hand off it when copying / pasting with the keyboard, which is a real pain when you work as a graphic designer

Comment: I appreciate that, but unless you're actually typing full paragraphs, for me I've always worked one had on keyboard, one on mouse & I taught a lot of others the same tricks [music software, not graphics, but a very heavily keyboard-oriented workflow] so it's one hand to click, the other to key command. Being musos, half my team were lefties & other than swapping mouse buttons over & moving the mouse to the left of the keyboard, I've not seen any of them struggle with the commands themselves. In that environment, pretty much the entire alphabet + all 4 modifiers were needed for some task.

Comment: I find it's a lot quicker to move my hand between a Magic Trackpad and the keyboard than the mouse. I can probably hit Command C and back in a fraction of a second. Or you could use your right hand to Copy Paste. It's not an inert stump, after all. (I hope.) As a lefty, I do try to avoid lefty customizations, (other than the mouse/trackpad being on the left.) But that's an extended discussion.

Comment: Sure, it's all horses for courses. Personally, you couldn't pay me to use a trackpad, I loathe them to the depth of my being ;-))

Comment: I too could not be converted to a trackpad even if someone paid me ha! I sometimes do use my right hand to copy/paste although I'm not a fan of having to awkwardly reach across the keyboard like that for a shortcut that I need so regularly... I'm not actually left-handed but thought I'd make the switch in order to stop putting so much strain on my right arm / shoulder